# Revel framework, db module, and gorp

Tags: database, orm, go, revel

Good day,

Trying to dive into **Revel** framework stuff. And just have faced something which seems strange to me. Trying to find out how to use Postgres.

There is a reference app (booking) which is using [GorpController](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/master/samples/booking/app/controllers/gorp.go). And `GorpController` imports [db module](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/master/modules/db/app/db.go). But what is the profit of db module usage if both the controller and the db module are almost similar?

Examples are plentiful:

```
type GorpController struct {
    *r.Controller
    Txn *gorp.Transaction // The only difference we have gorp.Transaction here
}
```

and:

```
type Transactional struct {
    *revel.Controller
    Txn *sql.Tx
}
```

And then we have 3 absolutely identical methods in both files, they are `func (...) Begin() r.Result`, `func (...) Commit() r.Result`, and `func (...) Rollback() r.Result`.

So why do we need db module if we are redefining most of the things in our controller?

Comment: What happens if you remove all of the `Transactional` methods and its `struct`?

Comment: @Brenden I think he has a point, that's not very DRY.. Shouldn't you take that as a bug report of sorts, and provide an answer here too... I think no one else dares, lol :)